# Hiding form fields for editing records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I'm trying to build my first ASP.net MVC application with Entity Framework. It's going fine but i have a problem. I'm using custom user system so i have a page for creating and editing users. In create view, obviously i have username and password fields but i don't want to have them in edit view. Problem is they have `[Required]` attribute so if i delete them from the edit page, values become null and it gives me an validation error. I'm probably missing something easy here, not sure.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need two models, one for create and other for edit

Comment: As always, use view models to represent what you want to display/edit in a view.

Comment: I thought about using view models and i also thought maybe there was an easier way to do it? So i should use automapper?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value to post to MVC on submit that you don't want to display, make it a hidden field via `@Html.HiddenFor( m => m.MyField )` in your razor view.

**Don't do this for passwords**. In fact, you shouldn't be able to render their password anyways, because you should only have a one-way encrypted copy.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that too but i need password field for creating the user record so i can't fix it that way.

Comment: I really suggest using different views for these actions.